# How do you represent collections of Hibernate objects in a single POJO?

Tags: java, hibernate, dao, hibernate-mapping

Consider the following Hibernate mappings:

```
<hibernate-mapping package="org.example">
  <class name="Customer" table="CUSTOMER">
    <id name="customerId" column="customer_id"/>

    <bag name="itineraries" table="ITINERARY" inverse="true" cascade="all">
      <key column="customer_id"/>
      <one-to-many class="Itinerary"/>
    </bag>

    <bag name="hotels" table="HOTEL" inverse="true" cascade="all">
      <key column="customer_id"/>
      <one-to-many class="Hotel"/>
    </bag>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

<hibernate-mapping package="org.example">
    <class name="Itinerary" table="ITINERARY">
      <many-to-one name="customer" column="customer_id" update="false" not-null="true"/>
      ...other properties...
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

<hibernate-mapping package="org.example">
    <class name="Hotel" table="HOTEL">
      <many-to-one name="customer" column="customer_id" update="false" not-null="true"/>
      ...other properties...
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Now say you need to remove the CUSTOMER table. How would you refactor the mappings/model such that the Customer Java object continues to contain Lists of Itinerary and Hotel objects based on a customerId? Said Hotel and Itinerary objects still need to be managed by Hibernate.

The best I can come up with is the Customer object deferring to DAOs when callers request a List. Is there a cleaner approach that will still allow the Customer object to live in each Itinerary and Hotel object?

Comment: Why would you want to remove the CUSTOMER table ?

Comment: It's really hypothetical, but let's say the CUSTOMER table was moving to some other inaccessible schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you remove the customer table, the customer object will not be managed by Hibernate anymore. If you still want to have a customer object containing Itinerary and Hotel, then that needs to be done programmatically. I am not sure if you are really looking for this.

One possible way of doing this is

1. Lets say you have a DAO with a method getCustomer(). This accepts a customer id.
2. This method fires two more queries to fetch lists of Itinerary and Hotel based on the customer id.
3. It creates a Customer object and sets the lists of Itinerary and Hotel into it and returns it and populated customer object.

Comment: Thanks, Santosh. Yes, that's close to what I have now:
1. Someone calls getCustomer(customerId). A new customer object is returned with a customerId member variable.
2. Someone calls customer.getItineraries(). The customer object simply defers to the itineraryDao to retrieve the itineraries for the current customer.

What would be ideal is multiple hibernate mappings that map the itineraries and hotels to the Customer object, but I'm not sure Hibernate works that way...